# How to specify url to load font from?

Tags: javascript, haxe, webfonts

I've noticed some examples that shows how to load a font from the current website being the base path for loading the font as:

```
Browser.document.fonts.load ("1em '" + font + "'").then (function (_) {
    promise.complete (this);
});
```

But how would I load from a specific URL rather than the website domain itself?
Also, what does `1em` mean?

**edit**

```
< style >
("1em url('https://lab-mywebsite.com.com/files/assets/fonts') ")
</style >
```

Comment: em: verticle size of the font and relativ to the size of the parent element. 1em is around 16px

Comment: and what about specifying the path to load from?

Comment: Don't know. Thats why I didn't write an answer ;)

Comment: Seems impossible with the current API.

Comment: "I've noticed some examples" — Where?

Comment: `Browser` — What is this variable? What defines it?

Comment: @Quentin Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API

Comment: Its a haxe based project for openFL, I will get it now, one moment please

Comment: here: https://github.com/openfl/lime/blob/develop/lime/text/Font.hx#L467

Comment: @simo According to the API docs, the `font` parameter accepts CSS formats. Have you tried using `url(` ?

Comment: canyou please show me how would I do so?

Comment: @simo Please try: `("1em url('http://fontsource') ")`

Comment: do you mean like at: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp ?

Comment: @simo No, that won't work. It's a shot in the dark, but try just like I wrote above. Only the `url` part

Comment: please see edit above, it had no effect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to explicitly preload a font from a url, you should use the `js.html.FontFace` constructor directly:

```
var url = "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v8/10JVD_humAd5zP2yrFqw6ugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2";

new js.html.FontFace("Indie Flower", "url($url)").load()
    .then(function (loadedFace) { /* do something with the loaded font */ });
```

For a working example, check out this [Try Haxe fiddle](https://try.haxe.org/#8733E).

---

As far I understood the CSS Font Loading Module Level 3 draft, the `FontFaceSet` API – the one you access via `document.fonts` – gives you control over the loading of fonts already added to the default set (e.g. via stylesheets/`<link>` tags).

You could check it out for more information on the [interaction with CSS font loading and matching](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-font-loading/#font-face-set-css).